# How to add tooltip to formly field

Tags: angular, forms, tooltip, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I was trying searching for answer but not efficiently, so here I am.

How to add tooltip to those fields? Tooltip would contain only one sentence and it's not complex.
I should do it for more fields, but for the example I'll show two fields.

```
 customerFields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [{
                {
                    className: 'col-sm-6',
                    type: 'input',
                    key: 'companyName',
                    templateOptions: {
                        translate: true,
                        label: 'Customer.companyName',
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    className: 'col-sm-6',
                    type: 'input',
                    key: 'legalForm',
                    templateOptions: {
                        translate: true,
                        label: 'Customer.legalForm'
                    }    
                }

}]
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for that is to make your own template or your own wrapper so it becomes more easy for you to extend it and those found here in the documentation
https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-wrapper
https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field

Answer (score 0):

tooltip:{
className:'tooltiptext',
content: "Please update in year format such as 10, 20"
}